# React Router v4, "A router may have only one child element" using multiple routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render a sidebar along with a main content area using `react-router-dom`. I could just render `<Sidebar/>` normally but I want to pass it the location prop because of another error I was getting where clicking a `<Link/>` in the sidebar would change the URL but wouldn't update the main content area. So rendering the `Sidebar` component using a route with no path I thought would always render the `Sidebar` AND let me pass the location. However I'm getting this error...

> Invariant Violation: A `<Router>` may have only one child element

Here's my code in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/sidebar'
import SidebarContent from './components/Sidebar/sidebar_content'
import Blank from './components/Blank/blank';
import Course from './components/Course/course';
import { Grid, Col, Row } from '../node_modules/react-bootstrap'
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  withRouter,
  Redirect,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'


class App extends Component {

  render() {

    const sidebar = <SidebarContent params={this.props.params}/>

    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
    const sidebarProps = {
      sidebar: sidebar,
      docked: true,
      shadow: false,
      touchHandleWidth: 20,
      dragToggleDistance: 30,
      touch: false,
      transitions: false,
      pullRight: false,
      open: true,
    }

    const CourseParent = (props) => {
      return(<Course courseID={props.courseID}/>);
    }
    const SidebarParent = (props) => {
      return(<Sidebar {...sidebarProps} className="Sidebar" location={props.location}/>);
    }


    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Grid fluid={true}>
            <Row className="show-grid">
              <Col className="col-md-2" style={{height: '100vh', width: '175px'}}>
                {/* <Sidebar {...sidebarProps} className="Sidebar" location={location}/> */}
                  <div>
                    <Route render={({ location }) => (
                      <Sidebar {...sidebarProps} className="Sidebar" location={location}/>
                    )}/>
                  </div>
              </Col>
              <Col className="col-md-auto">

                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Blank}/>
                    <Route path="/course/:courseID" component={CourseParent}/> 
                    <Redirect to="/" />
                  </Switch>

              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This Router only has one child element. Are you sure this is the file causing the error? Are you using Router anywhere else?

Comment: how does your `Sidebar` component look like

Comment: That was it! I forgot to remove another `<Router/>` in my `Sidebar` component while I testing...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There should be single  in your whole app and it contain only a single component. 
You can find detail about this at here:
https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf